# Site not found: freebsd.stackexchange.com

Tags: support

Issuing the following commands returns the displayed results:

```
$ ping -c 4 freebsd.stackexchange.com

Pinging freebsd.stackexchange.com [151.101.129.69] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 151.101.129.69: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 151.101.129.69: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 151.101.129.69: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 151.101.129.69: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 151.101.129.69:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 15ms, Maximum = 15ms, Average = 15ms

$ curl -X HEAD -I https://freebsd.stackexchange.com
HTTP/2 404
x-request-guid: 91d4d75c-cf9c-45dc-aea0-a5ffdb1061b7
accept-ranges: bytes
date: Mon, 23 Dec 2019 14:55:35 GMT
via: 1.1 varnish
x-served-by: cache-mad22044-MAD
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-timer: S1577112935.892355,VS0,VE110
vary: Fastly-SSL
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
set-cookie: prov=f1b9e1bc-4bf3-d056-52fe-6c343fdd9f7e; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
content-length: 3850
```

When I try to open the the link in a browser a page is displayed with the following message:

```
Couldn't find freebsd.stackexchange.com
The Q&A site freebsd.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…yet
...
```

How can that be?

Comment: @terdon I am trying to understand why the domain exists but the site does not.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I figured it out eventually.

Comment: the `*.stackexchange.com` are virtual hosts, which are usually implemented with [__wildcard dns records__](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) (the reason for those results), the required [`Host:`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4) header of HTTP/1.1, the [server name indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) of TLS, and [wildcard public key certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate).

Comment: subdomains do __not__ need to resolve to the same IP, and most of the time they don't (eg. `mail.google.com` will not resolve to the same IP as `maps.google.com`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `foo.stackexchange.com` names are subdomains, they all go to the same actual IP. For example:

```
$ for i in unix ubuntu apple workplace english french; do ping -c 1 $i.stackexchange.com | grep PING; done
PING unix.stackexchange.com (151.101.65.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING ubuntu.stackexchange.com (151.101.65.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING apple.stackexchange.com (151.101.65.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING workplace.stackexchange.com (151.101.193.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING english.stackexchange.com (151.101.129.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING french.stackexchange.com (151.101.65.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

You get the exact same response no matter what you put in front of the `stackexchange.com`:

```
$ for i in snotty snooty smelly grimy; do ping -c 1 $i.stackexchange.com | grep PING; done
PING snotty.stackexchange.com (151.101.193.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING snooty.stackexchange.com (151.101.193.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING smelly.stackexchange.com (151.101.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING grimy.stackexchange.com (151.101.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

There is no FreeBSD site on the stackexchange network, so you can't actually visit any site using the freebsd.stackexchange.com. Instead, you are taken to a landing page on the stackexchange.com parent domain:

[image]

This is a very common pattern. Most hosting providers, if not all, will give you multiple (even unlimited for higher end plans) `foo.yoursite.com` subdomains.

Comment: In https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558619/5132 there's a proper DNS diagnosis tool rather than `ping`.  (-: